AWS Cloudfromation Fn::ForEach does not accept values from Mappings
Below is my Resources Section in CFN template. I want to create AWS Route53 Record Sets but the problem is that I need to hard code the number for iterations for the forEach as can be seen below under RecordSetLogicalId. I want those to come from the Mappings section of the CFN template so that I can create unequal number of record sets in different AWS Accounts. For example 3 in Dev and 5 in Prod. When I try to use FindInMap or Split functions, I get a cfn linting error '[cfn-lint] E0001: Error transforming template: Fn::ForEach values must be a list of 3 elements'
Resources:
  Fn::ForEach::RecordSet:
    - RecordSetLogicalId
    - - Route53RecordSet
      - Route53RecordSet2
      - Route53RecordSet3
    - ${RecordSetLogicalId}:
        Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
        Properties:
          Name: !FindInMap
            - !Ref Environment
            - !Ref RecordSetLogicalId
            - name
            - DefaultValue: nonexistantclient-distribution
          Type: CNAME
          TTL: 90
          HostedZoneId: !Ref Route53HostedZone
          ResourceRecords: !FindInMap
            - !Ref Environment
            - !Ref RecordSetLogicalId
            - resourceRecords
            - DefaultValue: d3kk6er7266fqt.cloudfront.net

